# multiple Bootstrap-select loads very slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

when i try to put multiple selects on website (more than 20) it slows down jquery execution (with stop/continue alert) - is there a chance to optimize the code to load it faster - it takes minutes to load?

sample code

```
<td><select class="selectpicker" name="ref[240][sub_class]">
<option value=0 selected="selected" >A</option>
<option value=1>B</option></select></td>
<td><select class="selectpicker" name="ref[265][sub_class]">
<option value=0>A</option>
<option value=1 selected="selected" >B</option></select></td>
```

javascript at the end of the file:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
    style: 'btn-info',
    size: 1
  });
});
```

Comment: The following #bootstrap-select issues thread from others who have hit the issue, may help:
https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/291

Comment: Was also very slow for me but I was using an older version - 1.6. About 1300 options were taking 3-4 seconds on a refresh...  Switched to version 1.13 and the refresh is instantaneous.

Answer (score 6):

I was working with bootstrap select too.
This trick solved my problems about bootstrap-select rendering delays on page loading: it seems that on page load, dom element usually render before selectpicker, this is making the CSS "rescale" which cause an horrible effect.

Usually selectpicker takes 500ms for the first rendering, you can force the rendering after the element definition like following avoiding this delay like follow:

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="your_select">
   <option>...</option>
   ...
   <option>...</option>
</select>
<script>
   $("#your_select").selectpicker("render");
</script>
```

Guess it helps :)

Answer (score 6):

In my case it was also totally OK to simple take the

```
 $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

out of

```
$(document).ready(function() ...
```

Answer (score 4):

For me, forcing rendering immediately after the `js` loading made the `select` appear practically instantly instead of waiting for the entire page to load:

```
<script src="~/assets/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(".selectpicker").selectpicker();
</script>
```

Comment: As a note, I ended up not using at all Bootstrap-Select because of impact on performance. Had to choose functionality over aesthetics because of SEO.

Comment: Hi, what method you used instead? I m now on situation where there are 20k options and it loads slow :(

Comment: @Ingus - I used a basic `<select>` element because I only have 5 options. Did you look at Predictive Search? https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/52266/what-are-alternatives-to-a-large-drop-down-select-list

Comment: I found other method that will suit for my needs, but will still check your suggestion for future. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

For me, was problem with bootstrap conflict.
I use this in CMS Joomla, so loaded from me Bootstrap conflict with another(from CMS).
As I removed duplicate files - all start work good

Regards
OrdaSoft team

Comment: Appreciate the sharing of the resolution for your team, however I don't think this answer is very clear in response to the question without further details of the exact issue you had and resolved and how this relates to the question